# Fourier inversion of an expression which leaves strange term

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am reading a paper where there is the following:
$$\mathcal{F}(f)(k)=a|k|\mathcal{F}(g)(k)$$
where $\mathcal{F}(f)(k)$ is the Fourier Transform of the function $f(x)$ to the new variable $k$. The paper claims that upon inverting one gets:
$$f(x) = -\frac{a}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{g(x-y)-g(x)}{y^2}{\rm d}y$$
I understand that (provided all the function are nice as required) in the first equation, i can set $\mathcal{F}(h)(k)\equiv |k|$ such that I get 
$$\mathcal{F}(f)(k)=a\mathcal{F}(g*h)(k)$$
leading to 
$$f(x)=a(g*h)(x)$$
with $h=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|k|)(x)=-\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\frac{1}{x^2}$
which should lead to 
$$f(x) = -a\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{g(x-y)}{y^2}{\rm d}y$$

so my question is, what is the other term in the integrand of the second equation doing and how do i get it? (I assume the difference of $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ might be due to different fourier transform definition used by the authors and do not really bother me as much as $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{g(x)}{y^2}{\rm d}y$)

Comment: what is the definition of the Fourier transform that the author is assuming?
Have you tried to fourier transform the second equation to see if you get the first equation from it?